# how can I append database value to the select2 as selected using jquery in laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal, jquery-select2

I inserted the select2 value in the database using multi-select drop down, but when I edit the modal it returns no value in the selected value.
I am using jquery ajax with Laravel.

Form

```
<form id="userForm" name="userForm" class="form-horizontal" data-parsley-validate="">
   <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id">
   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Project</label>
   <div class="col-sm-12">
      <select id="project_id" name="project_id[]" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-live-search="true">
      @foreach (projects() as $project)
      <option @if (old('project_id') == $project->id) selected @endif value="{{ $project->id }}">{{ $project->name }}</option>
      @endforeach
      </select>
      <span class="text-danger error_message" id="projectIdError"></span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="saveBtn" value="create">Add User
      </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Edit jquery code

```
 $('body').on('click', '.editUser', function () {
      var user_id = $(this).data('id');

      $('#saveBtn').html('Update User');
      $.get("{{ url('admin/user') }}" +'/' + user_id +'/edit'  , function (data) {
          $('#modelHeading').html("Edit User");
          $('#saveBtn').val("edit-user");
          $('#ajaxModel').modal('show');
          $('#user_id').val(data.id);
          $('#name').val(data.name);
          $('#email').val(data.email);
          $('#project_id').val(data.project_id);
      })
   });
```

Controlller

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        return $user = User::with('projects')->findOrFail($id);
    }
```

Now output
[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: use : `trigger('change')` here : `$('#project_id').val(data.project_id).trigger('change')`

Comment: `selectpicker` or `select2` ?

Comment: $('#project_id').val(data.project_id).trigger('change') it is not working, I am using select2.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by this code

```
           var projects = data.projects;
           let optArr = [];
              for (var i = 0; i < projects.length; i++) {
                  optArr.push(projects[i].id);
               }
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', optArr);
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh')
```